# Making a chat bubble in css with border around ::before property

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i want to make a chat bubble in css with border around it.

The problem i am facing is to add border propery to ::before in this css, to give it a clean border.

As you can run my snipet and see that at top of ::before "box-shadow" property doesnt get applied, i want to make it exactly like the image posted above.

Could somene help me out with this?
Thanks

```css
/* General CSS Setup */

body {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
}


/* CSS talk bubble */

.talk-bubble {
  padding: 11px 16px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgb(126 151 179 / 70%) 0px 0px 3px;
  border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Right triangle placed top left flush. */

.tri-right.left-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: rgb(126 151 179 / 70%) 0px 2px 0px -1px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  top: -9px;
  left: -8px;
  border-width: 9px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #fff #fff transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="talk-bubble tri-right left-top">
  <div class="talktext">
    <p>This one adds at the top by .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Mention what you have tried . . .

Comment: hi @ManasKhandelwal i have shared the snippet in this post, i tried tinkering the box shadow property and border-width to adjust it, but got no success :(

Comment: This code is just copied from codepen!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal copied and refractored .....the class name and html are same but once u see css part thats not exactly the same , i modified it to my needs :)